# Fetch with Mocha.js in browser mode won't process or throw error

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, mocha.js

I'm pretty new to the whole 'modern' JS (implying, TS, TDD, Node...) so bear with me please :)

Anyhow, part of my app includes fetching data from the back-end and processing it with Three.js, [I tried a lot of things from the docs](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code), but each time it compiles fine, but nothing is displayed in the [browser](https://mochajs.org/#running-mocha-in-the-browser) (nor in the console).

Also tried [chai-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised), same result.
Async syntax, but I understood that was for Node...

I'd love some pointers on what I'm doing wrong, I'm starting to wonder if that even possible, even though, as far as I know the code is valid JS, that [runs into my browser] (latest FF).

Thanks in advance.

```js
it('A test what should fetch from the local api a json file', function(done) {
            // The url is just a random service I'm using for temporal test purpose
            fetch('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler')
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        done();
                    } else {
                        done('err');
                    }
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow *(I'd gladly have someone explain here if they get why)*, I fixed it by moving the HTML to my templates, accessing it with a clean controller (I'm using Symfony) and including the scripts with Webpack Encore.

```
// Like this
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('test_carto') }}
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('test_three') }}
```

I hope it will be helpful to someone.